# How to use io module with Chicken Scheme?

Tags: module, chicken-scheme

With Chicken Scheme, I want to use the read-lines procedure. With the interpreter (csi), no problem:

```
(define (lire-vecteur)
   (let* ((fichier (car (command-line-arguments)))
      (flux (open-input-file fichier)))
     (let ((V (list->vector (map string->number (read-lines flux)))))
       (close-input-port flux)
       (display (tri-rapide V)))))
```

But when trying to compile (csc) I get:

```
$ time ./tri-rapide-vecteur-lst ../mega-vecteur.txt 

Error: unbound variable: read-lines

    Call history:

    library.scm:3448: print-exit54375438      
    library.scm:2290: body3981    
    library.scm:2292: assign      
    library.scm:3448: current-print-length54395440    
    library.scm:2290: body3981    
    library.scm:2292: assign      
    library.scm:3926: ##sys#print     
    library.scm:3188: case-sensitive      
    library.scm:3189: keyword-style   
    library.scm:3190: ##sys#print-length-limit    
    library.scm:3297: outchr      
    library.scm:3188: g5148   
    library.scm:3927: print-call-chain    
    library.scm:3882: ##sys#get-call-chain    
    library.scm:3834: ##sys#make-vector   
    library.scm:1371: ##sys#allocate-vector     <--
```

read-lines is part of the (chicken io) module. How to import this module in my program?

Thank you for any hint, and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're using CHICKEN 5? It sounds like you're using CHICKEN 4. In CHICKEN 5, the interpreter generally should have the same modules available as the compiler, but it may depend a bit on what you're doing.

The correct incantation to import the `(chicken io)` module is simply: `(import (chicken io))`.